# how to share variables in different javascript modules

Tags: javascript, scope

I want to know if it is possible to share variables in different module.

For example,in my `common` module,I define some global variable and util methods

```
(function(){
  var name="";
})();
```

While in anothe module,I want to access the `name` variable,for example, in the `app` module:

```
var kk=name; // access the name
//other thing
```

However I do not want to export the `name` to global context.

Is it possible?

### Update

---

Why I ask this question is I found google do this:

In the google map [example page](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple):

It load the following js:
[main.js](https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/14/main.js)

Whose content is:

> ((function(){ //xxxxxx }).call(this);

Then it load the [map](https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/14/map.js) compnets like this:

> google.maps.**_*gjsload*_**('map', '\'use strict\';function Ut(){}function
>   Vt(a,b,c).......');

While the `map` module can use the variables in the `main` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

It's perfectly simple: if you open your console on the example page, and look at the source of main.js (click the button in the bottom left corner that looks like `[{}]`) you'll notice that the entire script is one big function, that is called using `.call(this)`. The latter is necessary because of strict mode (which shields the global object, unless it's explicitly set as caller context).
This function declares all functions, objects and methods in this function's scope, forming a closure. It therefore stands to reason that all functions declared in this scope have access to all variables, too. In the end the `google` property is assigned as a property of the global object, thus exposing the closure.

```
(function()
{
    'use strict';
    console.log(this);//would be undefined
}).call(this);//but the global object is explicitly set as context, so this === window

(function()
{
    'use strict';
    var closureScope = 'Global object can\'t see me';
    var google = {visible:'Yes, I was assigned as a property to the global object'};
    google.closureScope = closureScope;//expose initial value of closureScopeVariable
    google.showBenefits = function()
    {//context here is google object, this points to google
        this.closureScope = 'I looked like the closure variable';//reassign
        console.log(this.closureScope === closureScope);//logs false
    };
    google.restoreOriginal = function()
    {
        this.closureScope = closureScope;//reassign closureScope's original value
    };
    //expose:
    this.google = google;
}).call(this);
//global object:
google.closureScope = 'Foobar';
google.restoreOriginal();
console.log(google.closureScope);//Global object can't see me
```

For all I know this might not look all that clear, but essentially, what happens is this: each function has its own scope. All variables declared in that scope are garbage collected (GC'ed) when that function returns *Unless* there is an object that references them. 
In this case google is an object, declared in the anonymous function's scope. A **reference** to this google object was then assigned to the global object, it just happens to have the same name as the object variable, but it could just as well have been exposed like so:

```
window.foobar = google;
window.foobar.closureScope;//works
window.google;//undefined
```

Google is a property of the global object, that *references* an object created in the function's scope. The object it references keeps the function's scope (and all of the variables declared in that scope) alive. That's why it might seem that you have access to the closure variables almost directly, but again, it's a *REFERENCE*. If you're familiar with C(++) programming, here's what happens in pseudo-code:

```
GoogleObj google = new Google();
GoogleObj &window.google = google;
//or in pseudo-C:
GoogleObj *google;
GoogleObj **window.google = &google;//pointer to pointer ~= reference
```

Basically the global `google` contains nothing more then the memory address of the actual google object, it points to it, it references it, it just tells JS where to look for the values in memory,...
The actual object cannot be accessed directly, it sits somewhere in memory, along with all local variables that were declared along with it, who all have addresses, too, but the global object doesn't know about those. It just goes to the one address it knows of, asks for whatever it needs and the *original* google object complies.

I'm terrible at explaining all this in a coherent, comprehensive way, but [perhaps this article](http://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2012/02/17/javascript-closures-explained/) might shed some light on this matter. When I started to look into closures, I found the diagrams very helpful.

---

You can't, not as such. The whole point of closures is that you can set variables that can only be referenced in that specific scope. What you *can* do, however is use *priviliged methods*, or (not to good practice, but possible) full on assigning a variable to the global object.

```
(function()
{
    var name = 'foo';
    //do stuff
    window.name = name;//expose to global object
})();//THIS IS BLUNT AND DANGEROUS

var safer = (function()
{
    var name = 'foo';
    return {name:name};
});
console.log(safer.name);//logs foo
```

If you really, really need globals:

```
var safer = (function()
{
    var closureVars = {name:'foo'};
    var name = 'foo';
    return function(privateName,globalName)
    {
        globalName = globalName || privateName;
        window[globalName] = closureVars[privateName];
    };
});
safer('name');//sets window.name to 'foo'
```

But best of all, especially in your case (access certain *"private"* variables) a privileged getter would seem the best way to go:

```
var module = (function()
{
    var closureVars = {name:'foo';}
    return {get:function(name)
        {
            return closureVars[name];
        },
        set:function(name,val)
        {
            closureVars[name] = val;
        }
    };
};
var name = module.get('name');//sets a global name variable to 'foo'
module.set('name2',module.get('name'));//and so on
```

That should do it

Comment: @hguser: I've updated my answer, well, now I'm afraid it's just unintelligible dribble, but there's a link on how closures work somewhere in there, which might prove useful. Also check John Resig's blog on strict mode, and read some of Crockfords articles or watch his vids on youtube. It might take a while, but all of a sudden it'll all make sense, promise ;)

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. However I have two question:1 in the main.js, the first line,there is a funcion `aa`,and I do not find it is exported by `google.aa=aa` 2 in the map.js,it can access `aa` directly, just like `aa` is defined in the map.js directly. What is the problem?

Comment: There's more than 1 closure going on, so it can be confusing. I haven't got the time (and courage) to read through the entire, slightly obfuscated code either. What I can say, though, is that not _all_ functions in the closure have to be assigned to the exposing object. That function throws an error, so It's best not to expose it, otherwise you might write `google.aa()` by mistake, stopping your script. It could well be that an ajax method of the google object throws an error at some point, and for that the function aa can be called, but the method has that scope access,

Comment: That's what closures are for: preserve relevant code in such a way that other code, either an other lib, or code written by the user doesn't interfere with the inner workings. I can't seem to find that map.js you're on about, but provide a link and I'll look into it. I've been meaning to write an article on this subject for a long time anyhow. PS: don't want to nag, but if my answer was helpful, I do appreciate an up-vote... I think it's fair to say I have made an effort here

Comment: Thanks!. The map.js link can be found at my post. And here is a example: in the `main.js` there is a variable `m`(`m=window,da=Infinity,ea=document`) which refer to the `window`,and in the `map.js` you can find that the `m` is used directly(`m[Lj](this.f)`) while the `Lj` is defined at `main.js` also.

Comment: BTW,I accept your answer as the right answer though I am not very exactly get it now. And I hope we can make further exchange if possible.

Comment: Again, it's really hard to trace back as to what `m` or `Lj` or any of the other variables are at any given point, but I can say this: Looking at the map.js code, I noticed it starts with `google.maps.__gjsload__(//code goes here...`. When you use a method of an object, it stands to reason that that method has access to the parent object, being `google`, which in turn has access to all of the closure variables. But even so: `m` in `main.js` is a closure variable, which means that you can define another variable called `m`, that has nothing to do with the first `m` variable. What's in a name...

Comment: But to be perfectly honest, it's getting rather late, and I've just downed a bottle of wine (tasty wine, too!), so any attempt to decipher obfuscated JS has become rather tricky. I have begun writing an article on closures, though. ATM, it's more of a tutorial, I'll let you know when it's finished, or I'll rewrite the answer in a more clear and concise manner to explain this stuff better. It can be pretty daunting and abstract at first, but it's really easy once you get it.

Comment: I hope  your article will come soon .:)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED after correct criticism of Quentin and Elias**

You could define your module like this:

```
var module = (function(){
    // your module definition
    var module = {};

    // set name as a property of the module
    module.name="";

    // return the module object
    return module;
})();
```

And now access name outside of the module using

```
var kk = module.name;
```

Comment: No, in that context you are creating `window.name`, not `module.name`